# BaseInputConnection methods not called for physical keyboards

Tags: android, android-edittext, inputconnection

I have a custom `EditText` that supplies a Custom `BaseInputConnection` object in its `onCreateInputConnection()` method. The problem is that the methods like `commitText()` and `deleteSurroundingText()` are being called for soft keyboards but not called for physical keyboards (Tested in Pixelbook).

Answer (score 0):

I got all my use cases covered using `InputFilter` and `sendKeyEvent` inside `InputConnection`. The problem with `InputConnection` is that methods like `commitText` and `deleteSurroundingText` did not work for popular third party keyboards.